# How to specify StorageEncrypted when creating new assets from a transcode in Azure media services

Tags: java, azure, azure-media-services

I'm following along with the [Using AES-128 Dynamic Encryption and Key Delivery Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783457.aspx) tutorial. I am using the [Azure java SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783457.aspx) and I can't find a way to use the `StorageEncrypted` option for newly created assets (i.e. assets created as a result of transcoding). When I upload my high-quality source file I'm able to use `setOptions(AssetOption.StorageEncrypted)` when creating the Azure asset. I see in the [Encode the asset containing the file to the adaptive bitrate MP4 set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783457.aspx#encode_to_MP4s) portion of the tutorial that it is possible to tell Azure I want to use `StorageEncrypted` on my new asset from the following C# code:

```
encodeTask.OutputAssets.AddNew(String.Format("{0} as {1}", inputAsset.Name, encodingPreset), AssetCreationOptions.StorageEncrypted);
```

I found a few vague mentions of encryption in the [Task.CreateBatchOperation](http://dl.windowsazure.com/javadoc/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/media/models/Task.CreateBatchOperation.html) JavaDocs but it is unclear what they are used for or what values might make sense.

So, my question is: how do I tell Azure to use `StorageEncrypted` when creating new assets from a transcode using the Java SDK?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've found the solution in the [REST API docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974286.aspx). Basically just add a `assetCreationOptions='1'` attribute on your `outputAsset` element in the `taskBody`.

I'm thinking the Java SDK simply isn't on par with .Net (which makes sense given the source). You might be better off just using the REST API directly as there are several missing pieces in the Java SDK.

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct. We don't have that wrapped in Java SDK unfortunately.